# Spreading the load more evenly from a background thread

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a background thread which runs every 5 minutes. I am using `ScheduledExecutorService` for this. Every five minutes, I am making a call to one of my service and parsing the response coming back from that service.

```
public class ThreadScheduler {

private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void startScheduleTask() {

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    callService();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // log error
                }
            }
        }, 0, 5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    public void callService() throws Exception {
        // execute the service and parse the response
    }   
}
```

Now the above code is running in 1000 machines and they all are started at the same time, so that means it will make all the 1000 calls every 5 minutes simultaneously to my service.  I'm trying to spread the load more evenly over a 5 minute window. Is this possible to do by any chance with the above code?

I am just trying to spread the load more evenly on my service over the 5 minute window so that it doesn't hit my service at the same time which will put more load once all the systems are started up  simultaneously.

I came up with the below code trying to spread the load more evenly over the five minute window:

```
public class ThreadScheduler {

private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void startScheduleTask() {

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    callService();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // log error
                }
            }
        }, (int)(Math.random()*5*60), 5*60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void callService() throws Exception {
        // execute the service and parse the response
    }   
}
```

Is this the right way to evenly spread out the load over the 5 minute window or not.

Answer (score 1):

That will help somewhat, however the schedule is still fixed after the first bit of variability.  another way to spread the load even more would be to use ["schedule with fixed delay"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) and put a short, random pause in *every* execution (e.g. `Thread.sleep(Math.random()*5000L)` right before `callService()`).  that will cause more variability over time.

additionally, to test the variability, you could create a simple test program which prints out the current time (in milliseconds) instead of calling the actual service.  run your test program for an hour using different algorithms and graph the results.  pick the version which gives you the best spread.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Can you provide an example for "schedule with fixed delay" for my better understanding? Not sure I understand correctly.